# How do Export excel button in sharepoint 2010 ribbon works

Tags: custom

Can any one say me how to add code behind file for the custom action button in sharepoint 2010 ribbon for click event.

Regards,
Zakeer Ahamed.S

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great article on adding custom actions to the SharePoint Ribbon: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606.aspx